# CORS rules nginx-ingress rules

Tags: kubernetes, cors, kubernetes-ingress

I need to allow requests from multiple origins: `http://localhost:4200`, `http://localhost:4242`, etc., on nginx-ingress version 1.7.1. But I'm not able to do that for multiple origins, because `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: true` will not work with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"`. It causes the browser to generate CORS error. Maybe someone has a solution for avoiding this error?

this is my config

```
 annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stage.site.com/api/session' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The
>   value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must
>   not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is
>   'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
>   XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: It seems you need to work around this by setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value in a different part of your server-side code. See https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/2535 and https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1171#issuecomment-391988766

Comment: nope - this is not working also.

Comment: Hey @dezzinto, did you fix this?

Answer (score 18):

Add the annotation to enable `CORS`:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

Be aware that **the string "*" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials** (https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests), try with your domain list (comma separated) instead of *

Comment: Comma separated list doesn't work. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin` only supports one domain, otherwise it resolves to '*'. https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496

Comment: I'm using official nginx helm-chart and looks like this annotation related to CORS is not working.  https://helm.nginx.com, https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/#adding-the-helm-repository

Answer (score 10):

You can create a second Ingress, with a different domain and cors origin, directing to the same destination. Not the best solution but it works.

Or:

```
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
           more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, 
           OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
```

But attention $http_origin is allowing every origin!

Answer (score 10):

This is a fairly requested feature: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496

As a current workaround you can use the following snippet to define more than one domain for CORS: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496#issuecomment-662798662

A PR has already been submitted and waits for completion. So this should roll out natively during one of the coming releases: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/7134

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments this feature has been released.

The following snippet solves the issue:

```yaml
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com, https://another-example.com"
```

More information can be found in the docs: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this answer, this is not the case anymore, that feature request has been approved and merged, the docs explain how to do this: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors

Comment: I would like to warn everyone, however, that the COMMA is absolutely essential.  The example file you get doesn't have it, and if your URLs are just separated by a space, CORS will not work!  I wasted 8 hours on this.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated 2023:**

You can now add multiple origins as a comma separated value in `cors-allow-origin`

Example:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "https://example.com, https://another.com, http://localhost:8000"
```

Source: [Cors Allow Multiple Origin](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5496#issuecomment-1263611772)

Answer (score 1):

You can add following to your config to match your two origins against http_origin which ingress received in header and return add *-allow-origin only if pattern has been matched:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($http_origin ~* "^http://localhost\:(4200|4242)$") {
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nicola Ben answered above, but this work for me: (Add the annotation to enable CORS)

```yaml
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: mybackend-ingress
    namespace: my-backend-namespace
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: Content-Type, authorization
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: https://backend.your.url
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'true'
```